# Lua check if method exists

Tags: oop, lua

How to check if a method exists in Lua?

```lua
function Object:myMethod() end

function somewhereElse()
  local instance = Object()
  
  if instance:myMethod then 
    -- This does not work. Syntax error: Expected arguments near then.
    -- Same with type(...) or ~=nil etc. How to check colon functions?
  end
end
```

[image]

It's [object-oriented programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html). Check for functions or dot members (table) is no problem. But how to check methods (`:`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `instance.myMethod` or `instance["myMethod"]`

The colon syntax is only allowed in function calls and function definitions.

`instance:myMethod()` is short for `instance.myMethod(instance)`

`function Class:myMethod() end` is short for `function Class.myMethod(self) end`

`function Class.myMethod(self) end` is short for `Class["myMethod"] = function (self) end`

Maybe now it becomes obvious that a method is nothing but a function value stored in a table field using the method's name as table key.

So like with any other table element you simply index the table using the key to get the value.